# Iterator class using a square list

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I am trying to implement [squarelist](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/the-squarelist-data-structure/184405336) by using iteration that points to the head element.  I've create this iterator class to make my iterator id directional.  I just want to see if I implemented it correctly.

```
class iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag , Object , int>
    {

    public:
        iterator(Node* p=nullptr) : _node(p){}
        ~iterator(){}

        Node* getNode(){return _node;}

        Object operator * () { return _node->data; }
        iterator & operator ++()
        {
            _node = _node->next;
            return *this; 
        }

        iterator operator ++(int)
        {
            iterator  retVal = *this;
            ++this;
            return retVal;
        }
        bool operator < (iterator const& rhs) const
        { 
            return _node < rhs._node; 
        }
        bool operator != (iterator const& rhs) const
        {
            return _node != rhs._node;
        }
        bool operator == (iterator const& rhs) const 
        {
            return _node == rhs._node;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Its hard to tell  without more information. How do you define the `end` marker. Are member guaranteed to be laid out in contiguous memory (unlikely but possible)? Show us how you construct members of your square list and how you build the begin and end iterator for the list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple of real issues (rather than the imaginary ones previously pointed out):

Your code does not fully implement the requirements of iterator.

- You have not implemented the `operator->` as required by the iterator concept.
- `operator*` should return by reference.
  This is because `*x = t` is a requirement of iterator and without the reference this will not work as expected (or at all depending).

Without the container code its hard to tell if you can use the same iterator for both const and non-const iterator types. So sometimes its useful to provide const overloads of the above (but that will depend on usage).

see: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/trivial.html

You classify your iterator as

```
std::bidirectional_iterator_tag
```

This is an indication that you can go backwards and forwards with the iterator. In fact the concept means that your iterator must also support `operator--` are well as `operator++`.

See: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/BidirectionalIterator.html

The link you provide indicates that a square list is circular. So moving forward all the time you may never reach the end. But without understanding (or seeing your implementation) it is hard to tell if the current implementation will work.

```
    iterator & operator ++()
    {
        _node = _node->next;   // Will this ever reach a NULL
                               // Or do you have a special version of
                               // iterator that marks the end.
                               //
                               // Note: end is one past the last element
                               //       Which makes this doubly hard to
                               //       implement with a circular list.
                               //       But can be done if you use a sentinel.
                               //
                               // The default constructor suggests that the
                               // end is marked by a NULL but hard to be sure.
        return *this; 
    }
```

No point in defining destructor the default version will work perfectly. (As a side note: since it is not virtual there can be no derived types with alternative behaviors so making things symmetric is doubly useless).

```
    ~iterator(){}
```

This is perfectly fine.

```
        iterator  retVal = *this;
```

But just as a personal preference I prefer:

```
        iterator  retVal(*this);
```

As mentioned above (but without the container code it is hard to tell). Well this test work for the `end` iterator.

```
    bool operator != (iterator const& rhs) const
    {
        return _node != rhs._node;
    }
    bool operator == (iterator const& rhs) const 
    {
        return _node == rhs._node;
    }
```

There is no requirement for bidirectional iterators to have a less than comparison. Unless you really want to store iterators in a sorted container I would leave this out.

Note: A random access iterator does have a requirement for a less than operator. But it has a precondition that it can only compare iterators that are reachable from each other.

see: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/RandomAccessIterator.html

```
    bool operator < (iterator const& rhs) const
    { 
        return _node < rhs._node; 
    }
```

The second thing to consider is the sort ordering correct?

1. You are defining the less than operator in term of pointer arithmetic. Unless the object are allocated by the same allocators from a known block this is actually undefined behavior. For pointer comparison to be valid they need to be in the same allocated block.
2. Is this a good ordering? Youre ordering is based on their address (not the position in the container). So things may be in a jumbled up state in relation to everything else. This may be perfectly fine but something you should keep in mind.

### WHY The following answers is a complete waste of time and WRONG

So please stop voting for it.

> I learnt about its importance following discussions on one of the C++ working groups. It's a good practice to follow smarter people.

Yes but you have to also understand when to apply these principles. Some ideas contradict other ideas if you just use them bluntly. You need to understand each idea but also when to apply it.

The concept of `operator symmetry` is an important concept when used in the correct situation (no argument there). The problem is that iterators are not the correct situation and it plays no part.

But we have two competing concepts at play here. One: is symmetry is good. Two: auto conversion of types by the compiler is bad.

You have to balance the two concepts. In terms of iterators auto converting iterators is a **very bad** idea. You want to make the user of the iterator be explicit about any conversions (as the STL designers did (see below)). As a result the symmetry concept can not be used (as it requires auto conversion).

#### Why it makes no sense for auto conversion

```
 Container    x;
 AltCont      y;

 // You can not compare iterators
 // From different containers.
 if (x.begin() < y.end()) {
     // At best this is undefined
     // At worst this is undefined behavior.
 }

 // There is no logic to that situation.
 // SO because you should not compare iterators from different
 // containers the type of the iterator when being tested will
 // ***ALWAYS*** be the same type.

 // The type of the iterator is always `Container::iterator`
 // Its a required property of a container.
 Container::iterator  begin = x.begin();
 Container::iterator  end   = x.end();
```

Q: A but you can create other types of iterator from your iterator.
A: Yes. But this new type is not comparable to the old type.

```
typedef std::reverse_iterator<Container::iterator> reverse_iterator;
reverse_iterator rbegin(end);
reverse_iterator rend(begin);
```

The types are still not comparable.

```
 if (begin < rbegin) {  // Compile time error
 }                      // For a good reason
                        // there is no logical reason for the ranges
                        // to be equivalent.
```

You will also note it does not work the other way around.

```
 if (rbegin < begin) {
 }
```

Why you ask is this second case a big deal. Well there is no constructor on Cont::iterator to create an object of type `std::reverse_iterator<Cont::iterator>`. So in the first test above there was no way to convert rbegin into the correct type.

BUT there is a constructor on `std::reverse_iterator<Cont::iterator>` that takes an object of `Cont::iterator` so in the second condition we could be in a situation where `begin` is auto converted into `std::reverse_iterator<Cont::iterator>` and the expression would compile. But luckily for us the designers of the STL decided that was a **bad idea** and made the constructor `explicit` to prevent auto conversion and thus prevent the code from compiling.

#### OK so why is in Dangerous

Its also hides errors.
The above code will generally generate a compiler error (so you spot it and correct it quickly). But lets dig in and build the code as suggested by @vinipsmaker.

For this to work there either has to be a conversion from one iterator to the other or as he suggests a base class and a derived type.

```
 class IterBase
 {  /* Define iterator */ }

 class IterDerivedForCont1: public IterBase
 {  /* Define iterator */ }

 class IterDerivedForCont2: public IterBase
 {  /* Define iterator */ }

 class Cont1 {
     typedef IterDerivedForCont1 iterator;
     /* Other Stuff */
 }

 class Cont2 {
     typedef IterDerivedForCont2 iterator;
     /* Other Stuff */
 }

 bool operator<(IterBase const& l, IterBase const& r)
 { return TEST(l,r);}

 Cont1   a;
 Cont2   b;

 if (a.begin() < b.end()) {
     // You want this to compile?
     // Not really. But it will
 }

 // So in this case you are hiding errors from the user.
 // That could have been easily spotted by the compiler.
```

Answer (score 5):

You almost got the `bool operator < (iterator const& rhs) const` (same for other operators overloading) right.

The idea is to make the left operand behave semantically equals to the right operand.

You went one step forward with this idea by defining the argument type as `const&`. Then, if I create a class that inherits from your class, the following would work:

```
iterator i;
derived j;
i < i;
j < i;
j < j;
i < j;
```

The problem lies on objects implicitly convertible to iterator. They cannot be used as a left-argument for the expression. You loses the symmetry property.

Define as non-member functions and everything is gonna be alright. Declare it as friend if needed.

I learnt about its importance following [discussions on one of the C++ working groups](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/concepts/IAHQkYcbCDc/XhQGRiy7yywJ). It's a good practice to follow smarter people.

Comment: PS: I didn't look on the linked url nor the rest of the code. I'll be happy enough with an upvote (don't need the full bounty).

Comment: -1: Yes the symmetry thing is important in mathematical operations. But here you are asking for trouble by auto converting a node into an iterator (can you think of a situation where you want a node to auto convert into an iterator (I can't)) or a situation where an iterator converts to another type of iterator (as the only type of iterators you can compare belong to the same container). You should rather keep the `operator<` as a member and make the constructor explicit to stop auto conversion. The less auto conversion the better.

Comment: @LokiAstari: "make the constructor explicit to stop auto conversion" won't forbid auto conversion. Look for conversion operators. Also, I didn't encouraged the use of implicit conversion. And lastly, your approach does nothing but break simmetry, because the implicit conversion will still work for right operand. Can you think a reason why would you want to declare the operators inside the class?

Comment: Adding an conversion operation is not auto conversition. This is a situation where you have sat down and thought about an automated method to convert and then explicitly provided one. So yes explicit does prevent auto conversion. But it does not prevent conversion that you have manually programmed.

Comment: Why do I want symmetry between two different unrelated types. Can you think of a single reason where that would do anything useful (apart from hide bugs). You can not compare iterators from different containers (that is meaningless). So the types are never going to be different when doing a comparison. All you are doing here is creating symmetry when 1) none is required. 2) hiding bugs when auto conversion kicks in.

Comment: Basically your comments here. Take an issue that is important `symmetry` but introduce it into a situation where it is not relevant and causes issues. Yet you have not identified any of the real problems in the code. This answer is so bad it should really be deleted.

Comment: "Adding an conversion operation is not auto conversition.". Well, I don't know what is auto conversion. I know what is implicit conversion and explicit conversion. When you add a conversion function, you'll instruct the compiler to perform implicit conversion in certain situations. "So yes explicit does prevent auto conversion". `explicit` won't prevent me from implement an object implicitly convertible to your class/object.

Comment: "Can you think of a single reason where that would do anything useful (apart from hide bugs)". Stop the FUD. Implement operators as non-member functions will **not** hide bugs. "You can not compare iterators from different containers (that is meaningless)". It is **not** about iterators from different containers. You fail to understand what is going on.

Comment: No it won't. But that's a completely different issue. If I want to write a conversion function I will have thought about it carefully first. Because converion operators are dangerious. But again completely outside the scope of your suggestions. Which introduces unneeded symmetry (because it has no practical use) and introduces bugs because people think the comparison did something useful.

Comment: It hides bugs. Because you can now do comparisons on things that are in no way related. This hiding it from you. If thats not an easy way to hide a bug I don;t know what is. Your the one that is introducing irrelevant concepts to hide the fact your ideas a re silly and you applying technique just because you just learnt them without understanding why you should use them.

Comment: "Take an issue that is important symmetry but introduce it into a situation where it is not relevant and causes issues". Implicit conversion may have side effects. You need to carefully think about its consequences. But I'm not encouraging implicit conversions. I'm encouraging operators implemented as non-member functions. Can you cite one example where operators declared as member functions is better?

Comment: I think you are failing to understand what the OP is doing here. He has an iterator. You want it to work without introducing irrelevant concepts that are not applicable to this situation. The OP would actually want to find real issues with his iterator that you seem to have completely missed just to spout what you read in a book and don;t understand when to apply.

Comment: "Which introduces unneeded symmetry (because it has no practical use) and introduces bugs because people think the comparison did something useful". What bug? Can you enlighten me?

Comment: `What bug? Can you enlighten me?` Easy you can now compare two iterators of different types with `operator<` when is that ever going to produce a valid answer?

Comment: "It hides bugs". Two can play this game: It doesn't hide bugs. Now, can you show us a snippet?

Comment: "Your the one that is introducing irrelevant concepts to hide the fact your ideas a re silly and you applying technique just because you just learnt them without understanding why you should use them". This is the only relevant text you wrote in the whole thread.

Comment: `Now, can you show us a snippet` I point you at your code above with `i` and `j`. When are these values going to be valid. Such that the comparison actual provides a correct value. The answer never. Yet now they will compile but previously at least half of them will have generated a compiler error.

Comment: "Easy you can now compare two iterators of different types". No, you cannot.

Comment: Are `i` and `j` not different types. Are you not comparing them with `operator<` is this ever going to provide anything useful? When we are talking about iterators.

Comment: "I point you at your code above with `i` and `j`. When are these values going to be valid. Such that the comparison actual provides a correct value". They are valid. They are an instance-of base, which is the only needed thing by the implementation of the operators. "Are i and j not different types". They are instances of the same type, the `base`/`iterator` type.

Comment: So you have a class that gives out different types for the different methods that return iterators. You are now beraking all the conventions of container. A container is supposed to define its iterator type as a member type `typename XXX iterator;`. So there is only one type of iterator per container (not counting const versions). There is no ability to have base/iterator whatever that means. More misdirection without any substance behind it.

Comment: If you'd like to continue this conversation, please take it to chat.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jamal: I think I am finished. vinipsmaker obviously has nothing of importance to say.